# Javascript error in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, javascript, defined

My problem in ie browser only...

auth.js

```
Deferred.errorHandler = function(e) { alert('Unhandled error ' + e); };
function User() {
    SbApi.url = 'http://api.sindbad.ru';
    var user = new SbApi('User');
...
```

IE console: 
'Deffered not defined' on line 1 symbol 1
'SbApi not defined' on line 4 symbol 1

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Check the source where Deferreed/SbApi is defined. Is it being loaded?
'* not defined' is usually printed when the variable has not been declared.

Comment: You don't get the error in firefox?

Comment: maybe its SbApi user = new SbApi('User'); ?

Comment: @TheChange, it's Javascript and not Java.

Comment: Load the JS file where Deferred object is defined or instantiated.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - thats why I dont use javascript... thanks, didnt know that js is even able to do such stuff so I thought it would be done the same way as in java or .net

Comment: @TheChange, you should try it out, you'll kick yourself once you get the hang of it, like "Why didn't I do it sooner?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Deferred class hasn't been defined - are there any other JS file you need to load? Make sure they are loaded before auth.js